# Update one field when the other changes - Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, watch

I'm trying to essentially create a two-way calculator and I've chosen to use inches to millimeters as an example.

See the sandbox here: https://q8y4s.csb.app/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" v-model="inches" placeholder="Inches" />
    <br />
    <input type="number" v-model="mm" placeholder="Millimeters" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inches: "",
      mm: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    inches: function (newVal) {
      this.mm = newVal * 25.4;
    },
    mm: function (newVal) {
      this.inches = newVal / 25.4;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The issue is going from millimeters to inches. I'm not entirely sure what's happening but it seems like a feedback loop of some sort. I know I can use computed to achieve this particular functionality but I'd prefer to use watchers since there is more logic to the 'watched' fields in my project.

This [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vuejs/vuejs_watch_property.htm) uses meters to kilometers and accomplishes the same thing but I'm uncertain why millimeters to inches creates the 'feedback loop' effect

Comment: When you change from 25.4 to 4 it works is an indication of a floating number issue that JS has. You might want to look into computed getters and setters instead of watchers.

Comment: If it's an issue with JS won't it also happen with the computed property?

Comment: Not when you use computed getters and setters which you can avoid running into infinite recursion. Your issue is that with your use of watchers, the value returned is always a bit off and not strict equivalent, which causes the watchers to modify each other’s watched values, which in turn causes the recursion.

Comment: @Terry I understand. I have at least 12 fields in one part of a bigger process so I was hoping to avoid the verbosity of writing getters and setters for each of those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a safety valve to prevent the recursion. Something like:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isChangingMm: false,
      isChangingInches: false,
      // others
    }
  },
  watch: {
    inches: function (newVal) {
      if (!this.isChangingMm) {
        this.isChangingInches = true
        this.mm = newVal * 25.4
        this.isChangingInches = false
      }
    },
    mm: function (newVal) {
      if (!this.isChangingInches) {
        this.isChangingMm = true
        this.inches = newVal / 25.4
        this.isChangingMm = false
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching this for long time now. I am new to vue but the following solution worker for me it is in vue3

```
<template>
    <input type="number" @input = "changetag('1')" v-model.number="state.unit1" placeholder="-">
    <input type="number" @input = "changetag('2')" v-model.number="state.unit2" placeholder="-">
    <input type="number" @input = "changetag('3')" v-model.number="state.unit3" placeholder="-">
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      tag: '',
      unit1: null,
      unit2: null,
      unit3: null, 
    });

    function changetag(value){
      state.tag = value;
      if (value =='2')
        state.unit1 = state.unit2/2
      if (value =='3')
        state.unit1 = state.unit3/3
      updatevalue(value)
    }

    function updatevalue(value){
      if (value!='2')
        state.unit2 = state.unit1*2
      if (value!='3')
        state.unit3 = state.unit1*3
    }

    return{
      state,
      changetag,
      updatevalue,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[feild2 = 2 times field1 & field3 = 3 times field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCW9d.png)